# Bluetooth adapter suddenly not seen or recognized by Windows (7)

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

Bluetooth Has disappeared.

When I click on the little "up arrow" near the clock I see the bluetooth emblem, but the white part is red.

At that point, clicking on the Bluetooth emblem produces nothing.

This doesn't work:  Unplug BlueTooth Dongle and Plug it back in.

This doesn't work:  Device Manager, Scan for hardware changes

What do I do to find the bluetooth adapter again ?

As best I can tell, the brand name is IO Gear, "Iogear GBU521"

Worked yesterday, perfectly.

All I did was restart the machine about 9:00 a.m. today.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting again?  Did you try a System Restore back to when it was working (before 9AM today)?

Comment: Just did a "restart".  Will try a complete reboot next.

Comment: you might also consider a full power down / power up system reboot.  This could help unstick some stuck bits somewhere in your hardware.

Comment: Next on the list.  It's dinner time here, and this old clunker made by Sherman Tank Computers (C) will need that much time to reboot

Comment: @mdpc Did the trick. Don't like it (this clunker takes forever) but it worked, so thanks.